# Use context variable for file name in tFileInputDelimited

Tags: talend

I don't know what i'm doing wrong but I try to use a context variable in the file name field in a tFileInputDelimited. When I try to run it, I receive a message saying that "inputFile cannot be resolved or is not a field". Input file is the name of my context variable.

[tFileInputDelimited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seTmT.png)

[my context variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqpXb.png)

Comment: open the code view and check what it says there.

Answer (score 0):

Chose String instead of File for your context variable type. Anyway, it's just a file system path.